# Make error for stellarisware

Tags: arm, archlinux

I got a stellaris board to explore the power of arm. I'm using arch linux. I want to setup a toolchain based on eclipse, but if I donwload the SW-LM3S-9453.exe, unzip it, and try to make it I got the following errors:

```
[root@vaio stellaris]# make
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/erbal/src/stellaris/driverlib'
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/erbal/src/stellaris/driverlib'
  CC    adc.c
as: unrecognized option '-mcpu=cortex-m3'
../makedefs:186: recipe for target 'gcc-cm3/adc.o' failed
make[2]: *** [gcc-cm3/adc.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/erbal/src/stellaris/driverlib'
Makefile:41: recipe for target 'all' failed
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/erbal/src/stellaris/driverlib'
Makefile:46: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

What am I missing?

Comment: `donwload the SW-LM3S-9453.exe, unzip it` - are you sure that this is what you did / what the instructions said to do?

Comment: the instruction says just what I did :) http://kernelhacks.blogspot.hu/2012/11/the-complete-tutorial-for-stellaris.html

Comment: And you made sure to get all the dependencies beforehand?

Comment: I've installed all of dependencies, what I know. But I'm new to arch , maybe I miss something :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified which toolchain is being used? That error would be appropriate if you are trying to use the host toolchain rather than a toolchain built for ARM.

Comment: I tried to follow a tutorial, to build the toolchain. It said I can make it by make.

Comment: Right, but that makefile looks at variables to tell what toolchain to use. If I recall from stellarisware you should check a file called makedefs to verify any environment variables it needs are being set. By default it will look for arm-stellaris-eabi-gcc or arm-none-eabi-gcc in your user's PATH.